# Gazebo crashes when opening some example models

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all!
I'm new to Gazebo and I'm running version 1.0.1 (after compiling from tarball) on a 64-bit Debian Wheezy standard installation.

I'm able to launch successfully Gazebo and do some simulations; however, when I try to open some example models bundled with the program, Gazebo crashes.
Here follows an example.

When I try to open "cube_20k.model" I get the following output:

```
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Error [RenderEngine.cc:356] Unable to load Ogre Plugin[/usr/lib/OGRE/Plugin_CgProgramManager.so]...Skipping.
Error [Param.hh:227] Unable to set value [1,04719758] for key[angle]
Error [Param.hh:227] Unable to set value [0,100000001] for key[near]
Error [Param.hh:227] Unable to set value [0,899999976] for key[constant]
Error [Param.hh:227] Unable to set value [0,00999999978] for key[linear]
Error [parser.cc:548] XML Element[surface], child of element[visual] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[visual]
Error [parser.cc:539] Error reading element
Error [parser.cc:539] Error reading element
Error [parser.cc:539] Error reading element
Error [parser.cc:322] Unable to parse sdf element[gazebo]
Warning [parser.cc:241] parser for sdf version 1.0 failed, trying to parse as old deprecated format
Warning [parser.cc:247] parsing using deprecated world file failed trying old model format.
Error [parser.cc:253] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Dbg Unable to find element with name[model] return empty
Segmentation Fault
```

I get a similar behavior with many other model files, included the one used as example in the Wiki:
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Gazebo_models .

Moreover, strangely some much more complex models like "pr2.model" or "kitchen.model" load and simulate successfully.

What is my error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/49/gazebo-crashes-when-opening-some-example-models/) by [marcomurk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/41/marcomurk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I highly recommend upgrading to Gazebo 1.2.5. It is infinitely more stable.
The install process is also simplified, and will make upgrading much easier in the future.

-nate

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0